# Formatting input for currency with NSNumberFormatter in Swift

Tags: swift, nsnumberformatter

I am creating a budget app that allows the user to input their budget as well as transactions. I need to allow the user to enter both pence and pounds from separate text fields and they need to be formatted together with currency symbols. I have this working fine at the moment but would like to make it localised as currently it only works with GBP. I have been struggling to convert NSNumberFormatter examples from Objective-C to Swift.

My first issue is the fact that I need to set the placeholders for the input fields to be specific to the users location. Eg. Pounds and Pence, Dollars and Cents etc...

The second issue is that the values inputted in each of the text fields such as 10216 and 32 need to be formatted and the currency symbol specific to the users location needs to be added. So it would become £10,216.32 or $10,216.32 etc...

Also, I need to use the result of the formatted number in a calculation. So how can I do this without running into issues without running into issues with the currency symbol?

Comment: can you post an example of non working code?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Here's an example on how to use it on Swift 3.
( **Edit**: Works in Swift 5 too )

```swift
let price = 123.436 as NSNumber

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
// formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale() // This is the default
// In Swift 4, this ^ was renamed to simply NSLocale.current
formatter.string(from: price) // "$123.44"

formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "es_CL")
formatter.string(from: price) // $123"

formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "es_ES")
formatter.string(from: price) // "123,44 €"
```

---

Here's the old example on how to use it on Swift 2.

```swift
let price = 123.436

let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
// formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale() // This is the default
formatter.stringFromNumber(price) // "$123.44"

formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "es_CL")
formatter.stringFromNumber(price) // $123"

formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "es_ES")
formatter.stringFromNumber(price) // "123,44 €"
```

Comment: Based on the example you provided, I've managed to implement the number formatting into my program, so that bit is sorted. Now I just need to figure out how to set the text field placeholders based on the users location.

Comment: No need to cast it to NSNumber you can use formatter method func string(for obj: Any?) -> String?. So you just need to use `string(for: price)` instead of `string(from: price)`

Comment: @LeoDabus you're right, I didn't know about that method, I'm not sure if I should edit my answer though, as I think I'd rather use NumberFormatter's API and be explicit about using NSNumber rather than let it implicitly cast it inside.

Comment: Note that the result of formatter.string(from:) is an optional String not a String (as implied by the comments) so will need unwrapping before use.

Comment: The optional string return is an artifact of the conversion to NSNumber, here in swift-land we know that it's an actual number and that it'll never fail, so we could just force unwrap it.

Answer (score 27):

**Swift 3:**

If you are looking for a solution that gives you:

- "5" = "$5"
- "5.0" = "$5"
- "5.00" = "$5"
- "5.5" = "$5.50"
- "5.50" = "$5.50"
- "5.55" = "$5.55"
- "5.234234" = "5.23"

Please use the following:

```
func cleanDollars(_ value: String?) -> String {
    guard value != nil else { return "$0.00" }
    let doubleValue = Double(value!) ?? 0.0
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.currencyCode = "USD"
    formatter.currencySymbol = "$"
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = (value!.contains(".00")) ? 0 : 2
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.numberStyle = .currencyAccounting
    return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: doubleValue)) ?? "$\(doubleValue)"
}
```

Comment: No need to initialize a new NSNumber object you can use formatter method `func string(for obj: Any?) -> String?` instead of `string(from:)`

Answer (score 19):

I have implemented the solution provided by @NiñoScript as an extension as well:

**Extension**

```
// Create a string with currency formatting based on the device locale
//
extension Float {
    var asLocaleCurrency:String {
        var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
        formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
        return formatter.stringFromNumber(self)!
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let amount = 100.07
let amountString = amount.asLocaleCurrency
print(amount.asLocaleCurrency())
// prints: "$100.07"
```

**Swift 3**

```
    extension Float {
    var asLocaleCurrency:String {
        var formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.locale = Locale.current
        return formatter.string(from: self)!
    }
}
```

Comment: extension should be extending FloatingPoint for Swift 3 version and string(from: method is for NSNumber. For FlotingPoint types you need to use string(for:) method. I have posted a Swift 3 extension

Comment: Do not use float types for currency, use decimal.

Answer (score 19):

**Xcode 11 • Swift 5.1**

```
extension Locale {
    static let br = Locale(identifier: "pt_BR")
    static let us = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
    static let uk = Locale(identifier: "en_GB") // ISO Locale
}
```

---

```
extension NumberFormatter {
    convenience init(style: Style, locale: Locale = .current) {
        self.init()
        self.locale = locale
        numberStyle = style
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Formatter {
    static let currency = NumberFormatter(style: .currency)
    static let currencyUS = NumberFormatter(style: .currency, locale: .us)
    static let currencyBR = NumberFormatter(style: .currency, locale: .br)
}
```

---

```
extension Numeric {
    var currency: String { Formatter.currency.string(for: self) ?? "" }
    var currencyUS: String { Formatter.currencyUS.string(for: self) ?? "" }
    var currencyBR: String { Formatter.currencyBR.string(for: self) ?? "" }
}
```

---

```
let price = 1.99

print(Formatter.currency.locale)  // "en_US (current)\n"
print(price.currency)             // "$1.99\n"

Formatter.currency.locale = .br
print(price.currency)  // "R$1,99\n"

Formatter.currency.locale = .uk
print(price.currency)  // "£1.99\n"

print(price.currencyBR)  // "R$1,99\n"
print(price.currencyUS)  // "$1.99\n"
```

Comment: Do not use float types for currency, use decimal.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782982/how-to-input-currency-format-on-a-text-field-from-right-to-left-using-swift/29783546

Answer (score 9):

### Details

- Xcode 10.2.1 (10E1001), Swift 5

### Solution

```
import Foundation

class CurrencyFormatter {
    static var outputFormatter = CurrencyFormatter.create()
    class func create(locale: Locale = Locale.current,
                      groupingSeparator: String? = nil,
                      decimalSeparator: String? = nil,
                      style: NumberFormatter.Style = NumberFormatter.Style.currency) -> NumberFormatter {
        let outputFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        outputFormatter.locale = locale
        outputFormatter.decimalSeparator = decimalSeparator ?? locale.decimalSeparator
        outputFormatter.groupingSeparator = groupingSeparator ?? locale.groupingSeparator
        outputFormatter.numberStyle = style
        return outputFormatter
    }
}

extension Numeric {
    func toCurrency(formatter: NumberFormatter = CurrencyFormatter.outputFormatter) -> String? {
        guard let num = self as? NSNumber else { return nil }
        var formatedSting = formatter.string(from: num)
        guard let locale = formatter.locale else { return formatedSting }
        if let separator = formatter.groupingSeparator, let localeValue = locale.groupingSeparator {
            formatedSting = formatedSting?.replacingOccurrences(of: localeValue, with: separator)
        }
        if let separator = formatter.decimalSeparator, let localeValue = locale.decimalSeparator {
            formatedSting = formatedSting?.replacingOccurrences(of: localeValue, with: separator)
        }
        return formatedSting
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
let price = 12423.42
print(price.toCurrency() ?? "")

CurrencyFormatter.outputFormatter = CurrencyFormatter.create(style: .currencyISOCode)
print(price.toCurrency() ?? "nil")

CurrencyFormatter.outputFormatter = CurrencyFormatter.create(locale: Locale(identifier: "es_ES"))
print(price.toCurrency() ?? "nil")

CurrencyFormatter.outputFormatter = CurrencyFormatter.create(locale: Locale(identifier: "de_DE"), groupingSeparator: " ", style: .currencyISOCode)
print(price.toCurrency() ?? "nil")

CurrencyFormatter.outputFormatter = CurrencyFormatter.create(groupingSeparator: "_", decimalSeparator: ".", style: .currencyPlural)
print(price.toCurrency() ?? "nil")

let formatter = CurrencyFormatter.create(locale: Locale(identifier: "de_DE"), groupingSeparator: " ", decimalSeparator: ",", style: .currencyPlural)
print(price.toCurrency(formatter: formatter) ?? "nil")
```

### Results

```
$12,423.42
USD12,423.42
12.423,42 €
12 423,42 EUR
12_423.42 US dollars
12 423,42 Euro
```

Answer (score 3):

Updated for Swift 4 from @Michael Voccola's answer:

```
extension Double {
    var asLocaleCurrency: String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.locale = Locale.current

        let formattedString = formatter.string(from: self as NSNumber)
        return formattedString ?? ""
    }
}
```

Note: no force-unwraps, force-unwraps are evil.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4 TextField Implemented**

```
var value = 0    
currencyTextField.delegate = self

func numberFormatting(money: Int) -> String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.locale = .current
        return formatter.string(from: money as NSNumber)!
    }

currencyTextField.text = formatter.string(from: 50 as NSNumber)!

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    value = textField.text
    textField.text = numberFormatting(money: Int(textField.text!) ?? 0 as! Int)
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textField.text = value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Float {
    var convertAsLocaleCurrency :String {
        var formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.locale = Locale.current
        return formatter.string(from: self as NSNumber)!
    }
}
```

This working for swift 3.1 xcode 8.2.1

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Do not use float types for currency, use decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4

```
formatter.locale = Locale.current
```

if you want to change locale you can do it like this

```
formatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "id-ID")
```

// This is locale for Indonesia locale. if you want use as per  mobile phone  area use it as per upper mention Locale.current

```
//MARK:- Complete code
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    if let formattedTipAmount = formatter.string(from: Int(newString)! as 
NSNumber) { 
       yourtextfield.text = formattedTipAmount
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this function

```
func addSeparateMarkForNumber(int: Int) -> String {
var string = ""
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale.current
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
if let formattedTipAmount = formatter.string(from: int as NSNumber) {
    string = formattedTipAmount
}
return string
}
```

using:

```
let giaTri = value as! Int
myGuessTotalCorrect = addSeparateMarkForNumber(int: giaTri)
```