# Can't get a reference to NSNumberFormatter in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter

I can't figure this out, referencing this post: [Struggling with NSNumberFormatter in Swift for currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960621/struggling-with-nsnumberformatter-in-swift-for-currency)

I can't get a reference to NSNumberFormatter...i.e. I can't call any methods on formatter? (the below throws an error of expected declaration)

```
import Foundation

class CurrencyFormatter {

    var price = 100

    var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
    formatter.stringFromNumber(price)



}
```

[image]

Comment: What part of this is not working? I pasted it in to the Playground and it worked fine? What is your error?

Comment: I added a screenshot...I'm in a new file and a separate class, is there something else I need to import?

Comment: Oh, you probably need to operate on the formatter stuff in a function, not just sitting in the class. I posted some code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class CurrencyFormatter {

    var price = 100

    var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()

    init() {
        formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
        formatter.stringFromNumber(price)
    }
}
```