# Swift3: Type numberformatter has no member 'currency style', swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsnumberformatter

Seems to be many syntax's changed in Swift3 , I can't able to find the solution for this currencyStyle i referred the documentation didn't for replacement for this. If any one faced this error can you please hit answer below? 
the links i referred i mentioned below that works in

```
func getCurrencyFormat(amount: Double) -> NSString
{
    let amountFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    amountFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.currencyStyle -- ///ERROR
    amountFormatter.locale = NSLocale.system
    return amountFormatter.string(from: amount as NSNumber)! as NSString
}
```

[image]

Refered link it works for only swift2
[Struggling with NSNumberFormatter in Swift for currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960621/struggling-with-nsnumberformatter-in-swift-for-currency)

Answer (score 6):

`currencyStyle` is changed into `currency`

change this

```
amountFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.currencyStyle
```

into

```
amountFormatter.numberStyle =.currency
```

[image]

see the apple APIreference [Documents](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/numberformatter.style)