# Using the Same Currency Formatting in Multiple Methods

Tags: swift, swift3, number-formatting, currency-formatting, numberformatter

I'm using some currency formatting to set currency symbols/styles to the user's local settings.  Here is my code.  I think it works fine.  It is located in my viewDidLoad.

```
let currencyFormat = NumberFormatter()    
currencyFormat.locale = NSLocale.current
currencyFormat.usesGroupingSeparator = true
currencyFormat.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.currency
...
labelTotalAmount.text = currencyFormat.string(for: totalAmount)
```

The trouble is, I want to use this same formatting in two other different Methods.  It seems to be a waste to repeat the formatting for each method whenever I want to do formatting.

Is there a way to set the formatting once and have it remember the settings in every method of the class?

I'm using Swift 3.  I appreciate any help you can give!!

Comment: Use a class or global value, or a singleton.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960621/struggling-with-nsnumberformatter-in-swift-for-currency/42957137#42957137

Comment: FYI - no need to set the locale to the current locale since that is the default.

Comment: Ah, thanks for this too!  Thumbs up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a computed property of the class:

```
class Whatever {
    let currencyFormat: NumberFormatter = {
        let res = NumberFormatter()
        res.numberStyle = .currency
        res.usesGroupingSeparator = true
        return res
    }()
}
```

Now you can use that property in any method.

```
func someMethod() {
    let str = currencyFormat.string(for: 5.99)
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this is not working for me.  Perhaps I am putting the 'Whatever' class in the wrong spot?  I've located it both outside my class Viewcontroller: UIViewController and inside.

Comment: That's meant to be whatever your class is. Don't create a new class. Just make `currencyFormat` a property of your view controller class (or whatever class needs this property).

Comment: Thank you for correcting my stupid mistake!  Now it works wonderfully!  Thanks!!!