# currency formatter swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to format the textfield's input in currency standard format using its delegate method but the found solution is not upto the desire. I also found some solutions but nowhere i found the expected solution.

**Requirements:**

> UITextField's Input: 300000
>
> **Getting:** 30,0000
>
> **Desired Output:** 300,000

Using code:

```
//MARK:- textfield delegate method
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range:NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    
    guard let textFieldHasText = (textField.text), !textFieldHasText.isEmpty else {
        //early escape if nil
        return true
    }
    
    if textField == self.reqCourps || textField == self.presentInvest{
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        
        //remove any existing commas
        let textRemovedCommma = textFieldHasText.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
        
        //update the textField with commas
        let formattedNum = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Int(textRemovedCommma)!))
        
        textField.text = formattedNum
    }
    
    
    guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
    let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length
    return newLength <= 12 // Bool
    
}
```

**When i use `.currency` method it crashes the app also:**

```
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960621/struggling-with-nsnumberformatter-in-swift-for-currency

Comment: Add `return false` after `textField.text = formattedNum`. You should also remove all non-integer characters.

Comment: @Sulthan, by adding `return false after textField.text = formattedNum` i wont be able to edit textfield.

Comment: @vaibhav Well, do you understand that if you change the text and then you let the textfield to change the text again, you won't get the desired behavior?

Comment: @Sulthan, sorry didn't get point.

Comment: @vaibhav you want to convert your number into US currency right ?

Comment: $8,965,489,896,479,644.00 you want your output like this ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya, the ans you delivered which i was already using by sending whole string to apply currency sign and comma, but this time i am separating number using comma while enter in uitextfield see ques again.

Answer (score 2):

Here is code

```
func getNumberWithFormat(_ number : NSNumber, format : String) -> String {
     let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
     numberFormatter.locale = Locale.current
     numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
     numberFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true

     numberFormatter.positiveFormat = format
     return numberFormatter.string(from: number)! 
}
```

You can call this function like,

```
let number : NSNumber = 300000 
print("Number is : ", getNumberWithFormat(number, format: "###,###"))
```

Your output will be

```
Number is :  300,000
```

Comment: let me see ..wait plz.

Comment: can you please deliver me an ans which is directly passing textfild's value to above method, not static.

Comment: you can pass your textfield value to that function. For that you need to typecast your textfield.text to NSNumber.

Comment: thanks it helped me to convert into comma system

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to your locale settings. In some areas of the world, they have number formats like that. I tested your code and it worked fine, so I guess there must be something with wrong with your locale.

If you want the number to be in the US style, just set the locale explicitly:

```
// here pass your textfield value that you want to convert into doller.

 let price = NSDecimalNumber(string: self.textfield.text) as NSNumber
 let formatter = NumberFormatter()
 formatter.numberStyle = .currency
 formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
 formatter.string(from: price)
 print(formatter.string(from: price)!)
```

Output:

```
$8,965.00
```

Comment: if you talking about `.currency`  let me check.

Comment: if i set `Locale` with `.currency`, still crashes application.

Comment: its unexpectedly found nil, it seems when adding `formatter.numberStyle = .currency` with setting `Locale`.

Comment: @vaibhav that _is_ weird... I don't know what happened then.

Comment: I also dont know if you using the same code which i a using then why it crashes my app.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

open class DecimalFormatter: NumberFormatter {

    public override init() {
        super.init()
        locale = Locale.current
        numberStyle = .decimal
        minimumFractionDigits = 2
        maximumFractionDigits = 2
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override open func getObjectValue(_ obj: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>?, for string: String, range rangep: UnsafeMutablePointer<NSRange>?) throws {
        guard obj != nil else { return  }
        let str = string.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined(separator: "")
        obj?.pointee = NSNumber(value: (Double(str) ?? 0.0)/Double(pow(10.0, Double(minimumFractionDigits))))
    }
}


let originString = NSNumber.init(value: 30000)
let result = DecimalFormatter().string(from: originString)
```

you will get 30,000.00
if u want get 30,000, just change "minimumFractionDigits" to "0"