# How to convert string to currency without rounding up?

Tags: ios, swift, number-formatting, currency-formatting

I am using following code to convert string to US currency. However, I could not figure out how to disable round up.

For example, if the string value is "0.000012" code converts it to "$0.00".

The extension I am using it is from this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42957137/2303865):

The way I use:

```
print(Formatter.currency.locale)    // "en_US (current)\n"
print(priceUsdInt.currency)         // "$1.99\n"
```

Comment: `0.000012` rounded to 2 digits is `0.00`... so what is your question actually?

Comment: I do not want it to be rounded. I want it to be "$0.00012"

Comment: then please try reading the `NumberFormatter` [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter) first, focusing on the `usesSignificantDigits` and `minimumSignificantDigits` properties, perhaps...?

Comment: I will, thank you holex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control rounding (accept 6 digits after point in this case) add `formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 6;` to your `Formatter` extension

```
extension Formatter {
    static let currency = NumberFormatter(style: .currency)
    static let currencyUS: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter(style: .currency)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 6;
        return formatter
    }()
    static let currencyBR: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter(style: .currency)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "pt_BR")
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 6;
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

0.000012 is should NOT convert to 0.01 , that would be wrong.
If you want to set up a different format you can change the decimal points

```
String(format: "%0.3f", string)
```

Comment: Code converts it to "$0.00" not "0.01". I want to apply decimals into the existing code if possible. Thank you for the reply!