# How to find an integer in a string and insert a character right before the integer in Swift

Tags: swift, calculator

I am trying to make an expense calculator, where the user will simply type their expenses in this format "add Entertainment Movies 15" and the output will be printed as "Entertainment Movies $15.0".  Since this user could enter any text I wanted to make this dynamic where as soon as a number is found like 15 in this case, the $ sign gets put in front of it.

Just wondering what is the right approach of doing it in Swift?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question directly, but you can ease your life w/ number formatter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24960818/3397217

Comment: You might want to make the price a separate property. What if the user wants to enter `MacProok Pro 2018`? They didn't mean it cost $2018 (although it could have ).

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution with regular expression. It replaces *one or more digits* (`\\d+`) *followed by an optional dot and optional fractions digits* (`\\.\\d+)?` with the `$` sign plus the found partial string (`$0`).

```
let string = "add Entertainment Movies 15"
let result = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\d+(\\.\\d+)?", with: "$$0", options: .regularExpression)
```

Comment: See my second comment above. If the OP still wants the current solution, maybe consider using only the last `\\d`?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I just answered the question, it's up to the developer to handle the edge cases 

Comment: It sure is. I just thought it'd be a great addition to your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
func textDidChange(textField: UITextField){
    guard let text = textField.text else{return}

        if let numbersRange = text.rangeOfCharacter(from: .decimalDigits){
            text.insert("$", at: numbersRange.lowerBound)
        }

        print(text)

    }
```

Comment: guard `let text = textField.text` will never fail. Just unwrap `text!` property. Its default  value is an empty string. You can Also use optional chaining in this case `if let numbersRange = textField.text?.rangeOfCharacter(from: .decimalDigits) {`. This will probably insert the dollar symbol multiple times.