# String format for Double type number

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want my number to look like `25.250.450,00`

What string format do I need?

```
var myNumber: Double = 25250450
```

Comment: It does not look like you tried anything yourself, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Struggling with NSNumberFormatter in Swift for currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960621/struggling-with-nsnumberformatter-in-swift-for-currency)

Comment: I tried to show 25.250.450,00 like this but i couldn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare a **NumberFormatter()** and add all the functionalities you want. For this specific task, this solves it:

```swift
import Foundation
// import Foundation.NSFormatter 

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
let myNumber: Double = 25250450
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.decimalSeparator = ","
formatter.groupingSeparator="."
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
//you can add other parameters to formatter such as
//:-> formatter.maximumFractionDigits

let formattedString = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: myNumber))!
print(formattedString)
```

Full documentation of the `NumberFormatter` class is available at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter

> EDIT (SwiftUI variant):

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    func parseNumber(_ myNumber:Double)->String?{
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.decimalSeparator = ","
        formatter.groupingSeparator="."
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        //you can add other parameters to formatter such as
        //:-> formatter.maximumFractionDigits

        let formattedString = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: myNumber))!
        return formattedString
    }
    var body: some View {
        let myNumber: Double = 25250450
        Text("\(parseNumber(myNumber)!)")
            .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i don't understand to use in swiftUI, can u explain?

Comment: @Tahaylmz, They have not used SwiftUI.

Comment: The number formatter produces a String. You display it like you would display any other String. You would know how to display "abcde" in SwiftUI?

Comment: You can also add all these code in a separate func and let it return the already formatted string, which you can then use in your swiftUI View

Comment: Yeah, same as hear. But my struct not support this code block

Comment: I just added a function and it worked.. Let me adjust the answer

Comment: did you import Foundation?