# I want to add $ sign to TextField in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, textfield

Hi I want to add $ sign to a TextField when a user is typing.
[image]

This is my current code.

```
ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
  if price.isEmpty {
    Text("Enter total budget")
  }
  HStack {
    TextField("", text: $price)
      .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a Formatter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960621/formatting-input-for-currency-with-nsnumberformatter-in-swift

Comment: it may be reasonable to use the some kinda currency formatter with the `TextField`, it does not do the formatting on the fly during typing but it definitely formats the input value when the edit finishes.

Comment: Does your app only support dollars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

currency formatter is the way to go, but if you just want to show a $ in the TextField as you type, you could use something like this:
(you can of course combine this approach with a Formatter)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var price = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                if price.isEmpty {
                    Text("Enter total budget")
                }
                HStack {
                    TextField("", text: Binding(
                        get: { price },
                        set: { newVal in
                        if price.starts(with: "$") {
                            price = newVal
                        } else {
                            price = "$" + newVal
                        }
                    })).keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                }
            }.padding(20)
            Text("number entered: " + String(price.dropFirst()))
        }
    }
}
```