# How do I format a Decimal number as currency in Swift?

Tags: swift, decimal

I'm trying to figure out the right way to format a Decimal number as a currency value in Swift.

For example, if the Decimal contains the value 25.1 I'd want this to print as "$25.10". If it had the value 25, I'd want "$25.00". If it happened to contain a value like 25.4575, I'd want to round it off and display "$25.46".

There are a confusing amount of functions surrounding Decimals and string formatting. I know I can't just use String(format: "%.2f", value) like I can do with floats and doubles.

There appears to be a new FormatStyle property of Decimal, but I can't use that yet because it requires iOS 15.

Thanks, Frank

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42957137/2303865

Answer (score 1):

NSNumberFormatter has a currency style:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency

let number1 = Decimal(25.0)
print(numberFormatter.string(for: number1))

let number2 = Decimal(25.4575)
print(numberFormatter.string(for: number2))
```

Comment: Good answer (voted.) Note that you can use the function `string(from:)` (defined in the parent `Formatter` class) and avoid having to convert the value to an NSNumber.

Comment: Also, given that the OP specifically asked to convert a Decimal value to a String, you should probably have used a `Decimal` type in your answer, e.g. `let number1 = Decimal(string: "25.00")` and `print(numberFormatter.string(for: number1)!)`

Comment: OK.  I updated the sample.